# integrating nodejs rest services with wso2

Tags: node.js, wso2, authorization, wso2-identity-server

have my rest webservices written in nodejs. I want to implement role based[admin,user,super admin etc] authorisation for these API's
How can use wso2 with NodeJS ?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WSO2 API Manager for this. [Here is a nice article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/12/article-role-based-access-control-for-apis-exposed-via-wso2-api-manager-using-oauth-2.0-scopes/) on how to do that. And [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-OAuthscopes) is official documentation.

EDIT: You can read the complete product documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/api-manager-documentation).

And, there is an [API Manager Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud/) offering too.

Comment: Thanks.how is the workflow? Will the Client has to talk to API Manager and API manager in tun will invoke the rest web services  Or will the Client talk to API Manager and get a token and Then Client has to invoke the rest service with the token?

Comment: It's the former. Your services are fronted by APIM's proxy APIs.

Comment: Danke.
Thanks .I undestood it.
Can API manager handle my authentication as well? or  have I to use a combo of API Manager with WSO2 identity server.
Whats the best way to handle authentication(login) and authorisation [roles] togother?

Comment: APIM alone is enough to secure and manage your services. APIM supports OAuth2 for authentication, and you can use scopes for authorization as mentioned before. You can read product documentation here. https://docs.wso2.com/api-manager-documentation. 

Updated my answer too.